# Which is the best way to send wifi credentials from an APP (Android Studio) to ESP32?

Tags: android, wifi, credentials, esp32

As the question says, i was wondering if there is a safe, and non really complex way to send credentials from an APP to an ESP32, in this moment i made an app that connect via bluetooth and send the credentials via serial and it works, but this way has 2 issues, 1) its not safe (not encrypted/secured data), 2) you have to ask in the application the credentials (SSID and password of the wifi) and i think it should exist some way that avoids asking for data that is already known by the smartphone. Any guidance on this topic will be welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: would you want any android applications to be able to read your wifi password?

Comment: No, just my app, i want that app to be able to get credentials and send them securely

Comment: how should the OS know that it is 'your' app and not some app which wants to steal your wifi password?

Comment: asking for permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

all apps which are used to configure devices like IoT hardware and smart devices, ask the user to enter the wifi credentials when configuring the device, which is then transferred via Bluetooth or wifi connection,(the device acts as an access point, mobile with app connects to that devices' AP). you can save credentials one time and automate the process of sending them afterward.